# CRM 365 - Managed solution import does not remove event handlers

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, eventhandler

A form in our UAT environment contains falsely 2 event handlers on a field.

I have created a solution in DEV environment, in which I included the same form, which only has 1 event handler on the specific field.

When I imported the solution in UAT, the field continued to have 2 event handlers on it.

I tried both updating and upgrading the solution in UAT, but the field still has 2 event handlers.

I do not want to update the UAT environment in the default solution, and create an unmanaged layer in order to fix the issue.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason is that you have some unmanaged solution layer(s) on your form, you can check and delete it, [more detail here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/solution-layers)